# How do I scale a text element (h1) based on its length?

Tags: html, css

I want to scale a h1 element on the whole screen, both based on the screen's width as well as the elements width. How do I do that?

```css
h1 {
      font-size: clamp(6rem, 12vw, 20rem);
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<h1>Hey</h1>
```

this is the code for scaling based on the screen's width, but i have no idea how to scale it do it doesnt go on another line.

Comment: hello @Vladutzu27, 
I'm not sure but maybe you want to use [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to make rules according to screen sizes

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez well, this works and for this i cannot stick to just a few sizes. Its specifically designed for it to work on any window size, because its part of a show gig (not really a real tv show, but im working on a game which simulates it)

Comment: Using `white-space: nowrap` will work? This makes your text to stay on the same line

Comment: So you are not looking for "scaling" it but rather for decreasing its font-size when it is longer, to ensure it will stay in single line, right?

Comment: What about characters count and size? Do you use a monospace font? Is the characters count variable? You'll most likely need JavaScript. CSS is not meant to  inversely apply a content-width value to font-size in recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You need some information to do that.

You need to know the text length and you need to know the ratio of the width/height of the specific font you are using (*assuming it is a fixed width font*).

Having this info allows you to do the following calculation `100vw / (character_count * font_ratio)` to find the font-size you need to use that will fill the screen with the current text.

Here is an example, using the Roboto Mono font and dynamically updating a css variable with the text length, as you are typing in the green box.

```js
function updateTextLength(element) {
  const text = element.textContent;
  element.style.setProperty("--text-length", text.length);
}

const fitElement = document.querySelector('.fit')

fitElement.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  updateTextLength(event.currentTarget);
});


// initial setup
updateTextLength(fitElement);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fit {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;
  font-size: clamp( 2vw, calc(100vw / (var(--text-length) * var(--font-ratio))), 40vw);
  min-height: 1em;
  background: #bada55;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fit" style="--text-length:10;--font-ratio:0.61" contenteditable>EDITABLE TEXT</h1>
```